# What's the best practise if I want to fetch data from two table?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have two tables,

```
agent(id, name, password, ..., shop_id);
shop(id, name, address, ...);
```

Now I want to fetch the shop name for an agent, what should I do?
Should I use two sequence sql queries,

```
<?php
$qstr = <<<SQL
SELECT * FROM agent WHERE id=$id;
SQL;
$result = $conn->query($qstr);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
foreach ($row as $key => $value)
    $$key = $value;

$qstr = <<<SQL
SELECT name FROM shop WHERE id=$shop_id;
SQL;
$result = $conn->query($qstr);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$shop_name = $row['name'];
?>
```

Or should I create a view for this select,

```
CREATE VIEW f_agent AS SELECT agent.id AS id ,agent.name AS name, shop.id AS shop_id, shop.name AS shop_name FROM agent, shop WHERE agent.shop_id=shop.id;
```

Or should I just use the sql,

```
SELECT agent.id AS id ,agent.name AS name, shop.id AS shop_id, shop.name AS shop_name FROM agent, shop WHERE agent.shop_id=shop.id and agent.id=$id;
```

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is just a specific query you will use in a page in the front end, the simple SQL should work best.
No point creating a view for EVERY SINGLE possible result set that you want from MySQL.

If I can make a suggestion however, please consider the SQL92 ANSI syntax

```
SELECT agent.id AS id ,agent.name AS name, shop.id AS shop_id, shop.name AS shop_name
FROM agent
INNER JOIN shop ON agent.shop_id=shop.id
WHERE agent.id=$id;
```

Under **no** circumstance should you multi-trip to MySQL from PHP using the loop for such a lookup column for the result set.

Comment: so join query is faster than the sequence queries?

Comment: It helps the DBMS figure out exactly how the tables are related so that it can optimize better, so that you get more predictable queries. Often times, it is no quicker, but it is also good practice for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a view for such a simple query and using two separate results seems pointless so i'd suggest using the last query

Answer (score 0):

I am new to running queries like this, but I find this thread very informative. Would something like this work as well?

```
$query = "SELECT shop.id, shop.name, agent.name FROM shop LEFT JOIN agent ON shop.id = agent.id";

$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo $row['shop']['name']. " - ". $row['agent']['name'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```